# Right people to contact to get a beta community blog on Blog Overflow?

Tags: support, blog-overflow

[Cooking.SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) would like to set up a beta community blog on Blogoverflow. We have [post ideas](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1408/question-ideas-for-a-hypothetical-blog), [volunteers to write and run it](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/call-for-participation-cooking-blog), and an [idea of its scope](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1399/scope-of-a-hypothetical-blog). We've been discussing setting up the blog a fair bit recently in [#TheFryingPan](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16/the-frying-pan), and we think we have a schedule (every other week) to start with.

But, we're not quite sure how to actually get the blog set up. The [Stack Exchange Community Blogs](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115/stack-exchange-community-blogs) room was frozen, so one of our mods un-froze it, but a [question there](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4110865#4110865) hasn't elicited a response. (Nor did an earlier attempt in The Frying Pan).

So, the question is, how do we move forward with setting up a blog for Cooking.SE?

Comment: I see that you've already followed all the steps, but I wanted to post this link to the [guidelines for getting a Stack Exchange community blog started](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/) for those who haven't seen it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're slated to get a blog, ASAP. We're just waiting on some technical issues and, hopefully, the new beta design. Worse case, we'll launch with the Sketchy theme, but the whole process has been a bit backlogged. It wasn't intentionally, and sorry for the delays. It's coming.